# Python accepting user input and deleting that input from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have been trying this for a few days now. I have to read in a file containing zoo animals. (i.e. ['ID', 'Name', 'Species']) Next, have to accept the user's ID choice and delete from the list. This is what I so far. I am stuck and can't proceed further until this section is complete. I appreciate any comments. Also using python 3.

```
f = open('ZooAnimals.txt', 'r') #read in file
file = [line.split(',') for line in f.readlines()] #turn file into list
c = input("What ID would you like to delete? ") #accept user input
file1 = list(c)#turn user input into a list item
list.pop(file1) #suppose to pop out the value
print(file)
```

EDIT:

The file contains the following items for example.
[['1', 'Whiskers', 'Siberian Tiger\n'], ['2', 'Babbity', 'Belgian Hare\n'], ['3', 'Hank', 'Spotted Python\n'], ['17', 'Larry', 'Lion\n'], ['10', 'Magilla', 'Eastern Gorilla\n'], ['1494', 'Jim', 'Grizzy Bear\n']]

I want to try and delete for example, ID 2, Babbity, Belgian Hare

This is what I can't do with my current code

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: I cannot delete the ID from the file I am reading in

Comment: Do you have to use a nested `list` (e.g. for an assignment), or can you use a more appropriate data structure?

Answer (score 4):

`list.pop` accepts an `index` as an argument. For lists, this can only be an integer. Also, `list('abc') != ["abc"]`, but rather `["a", "b", "c"]` because of `str`'s iteration protocol (it goes by letter).

```
with open("ZooAnimals.txt") as zoo_animals_txt:
    # [("123", "cat", "felis catus"), ...]
    animals = [line.split(",") for line in zoo_animals_txt]

user_input = input("What ID would you like to delete? ")

for index, (id_, name, species) in enumerate(animals):
    if id_ == user_input:
        animals.pop(index)
        break

print("The remaining animals are:")
print(*animals, sep="\n")
```

Then, to update the file with the change:

```
with open("ZooAnimals.txt", "w") as zoo_animals_txt:
    for animal_stats in animals:
        print(",".join(animal_stats), file=zoo_animals_txt)
```

Comment: Did you also want this change reflected in the file?

Comment: I was about to figure that out. Would i change "with open("ZooAnimals.txt") as zoo_animals_txt:" to "with open("ZooAnimals.txt", 'w+') as zoo_animals_txt:"

EDIT: nevermind that totally erases the file

Comment: I added a way to update the file in my answer. Edit: Also, `w+` as the mode for opening the file truncates (erases) the file first, while `r+` will not. I chose to just reopen the file.

Comment: @SethBulliard please give me him an upvote and add it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

`list.pop()` removes the last element of a list. You probably want `file.remove(c)`. Also, remove `file1 = list(c)`. I'm not sure why that's there.

Comment: TypeError: descriptor 'remove' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'

Comment: The ID isn't the whole item. The file is turned into a `list` with nested `list`s. For `list.remove(c)` to work (although I seriously wouldn't recommend overriding the buil-in `list`), `c` would have to be something like `['3', 'Bob', 'Lion']`. Also, `pop()` can remove and return a specific element of a `list` if you pass it the index, e.g. `[1,2,3].pop(2)` returns `3`.